# Where is the stub instantiated in RMI

Tags: java, rmi

I am not sure where the instance of a stub for a remote object is created. Is it created when registering it in the rmiregistry by calling calling [Naming.bind](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/rmi/Naming.html#bind(java.lang.String,%20java.rmi.Remote))? This would make sense as the registry is also called via RMI.

But can't the stub also be created by calling [UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/rmi/server/UnicastRemoteObject.html#exportObject(java.rmi.Remote))?

This particular code snippet [from oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/implementing.html) confused me:

```
Compute engine = new ComputeEngine();
Compute stub = (Compute) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(engine, 0);
String name = "Compute";
Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry();
registry.rebind(name, stub);
```

When using Naming.bind do I need to pass a stub or a remote object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stub is

1. created when you export the remote object
2. substituted for the remote object when you pass the remote object as a remote method parameter or result, e.g. when binding or looking up in the Registry.

> When using `Naming.bind()` do I need to pass a stub or a remote object?

Either. It doesn't matter, because of (2).